# shopt not found in win-bash

Tags: windows, bash, win-bash

I'm trying to use win-bash in order to get a script to run on both mac and windows but shopt seems to be missing.
I'm trying to run

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Is there any way to do this in win-bash?

Answer (score 0):

win-bash doesn't have an equivalent of expand_aliases; thus, one cannot use aliases when the shell is not interactive.

You could use functions, e. g.

```
function name { command $* }
```

instead of

```
alias name=command
```